# How create a clickable icon link with high_voltage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, high-voltage

I use the high_voltage gem for creating links to static pages in my rails application. How can I use a picture / icon as a link? I just need some syntax example.
 Thanks, Karsten

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly you have links that lead to static pages you build with `high_voltage` gem.

To build a link with an icon:

```
<%= link_to page_path('page') do %>
  <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> # or any other html icon
<% end %>
```